# Correct the spellings of words in string with the help of a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have an input list where the spelling of REJECTED is written as RE1ECTED and DATE is written as OATE.
I need to correct the spelling and get an output list as:

```
output_list = ["REJECTED 00000 00000","DATE TIME =06/27/18 21 37","NACH NE NO XY"]
```

I am able to get the corrected list individually but not like the concatenated on shown above. Can I expect some advice?

```
input_list = ["=RE1ECTED 00000 00000",'OATE TIME =06/27/18 21 37','NACH NE NO xy']
Reg_dictionary = {"REJECTED" : ["=RE"],"DATE" : ["OA","DA"] }
for key,value in Reg_dictionary.items():
    temp = [key, value]
    for each_value in value:
        for string_list in input_list:
            count  = -1
            # print (count_number_of_string)
            each_in_string  = string_list.split(" ")
            for each_word in each_in_string:
                count = count + 1
                if each_value in each_word:
                    # print (count)
                    # print (string_list)
                    # print(each_word)
                    # print (key)
                    # print(each_in_string)
                    (each_in_string[count]) =key
                    print(each_in_string)
```

output from print(each_in_string) is this:

```
['REJECTED', '00000', '00000']

['DATE', 'TIME', '=06/27/18', '21', '37']
```

Expected output is:

```
output_list = ["REJECTED 00000 00000","DATE TIME =06/27/18 21 37","NACH NE NO XY"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the elements in the list and then the lists together. You can join the elements in the list with space as a separator between elements like this: `' '.join(your_list)` and that will give you the string. Then just concatenate the 2 strings together with `[string_1 + ' ' + string_2`]. That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from functools import reduce 

input_list = ["=RE1ECTED 00000 00000",'OATE TIME =06/27/18 21 37','NACH NE NO xy']
Reg_dictionary = {"REJECTED" : ["=RE"],"DATE" : ["OA","DA"] }
l = []
for key,value in Reg_dictionary.items():
    temp = [key, value]
    for each_value in value:
        for string_list in input_list:
            count  = -1
            # print (count_number_of_string)
            each_in_string  = string_list.split(" ")
            for each_word in each_in_string:
                count = count + 1
                if each_value in each_word:
                    # print (count)
                    # print (string_list)
                    # print(each_word)
                    # print (key)
                    # print(each_in_string)
                    (each_in_string[count]) =key
                    #print(each_in_string)
                    l.append(reduce(lambda x,y: x+' '+y, each_in_string)) # added this line
print(l)
```

Comment: Hi @Rodwan Bakkar Thank you for the help I needed an output which has all the three strings. output_list = ["REJECTED 00000 00000","DATE TIME =06/27/18 21 37","NACH NE NO XY"]

Comment: To get that, according to your approach you have t oadd something like `Reg_dictionary = {"REJECTED" : ["=RE"],"DATE" : ["OA","DA"], "NACH" : ["NA"] }` but this is not the right way, your code is a bit confusing.